# Get another J-1 while one is still active

Tags: j1-visas

I'm European, not under the "two years residency" requirement and am currently doing an internship for one year under a J-1 visa.

Is it possible to cancel it to start another internship elsewhere before the first one expires?

For instance, starting a J-1 short-term scholar in another company before the first visa expires?

Otherwise, from what I understand there is a three month delay between two J-1 visas. Let's say I've got six months left with my current visa.

Is it possible to cancel my current J-1, return to my country for three months and get a new J-1?

Is there any other option than the J-1 visa for a short term internship?

Comment: Are they under the same [category](http://international.syr.edu/su-departments/j1-exchange-visitors/j1-categories.html) and which category do you currently belong to, Student Intern?

Comment: I'm under J1-Student Intern yes. And the other J1 would probably be the same (or maybe J-1 Short-Term Scholar if J1-Student intern is not possible)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Is it possible to cancel it to start another internship elsewhere before the first one expire ? *It is called a transfer, it must be under the same category and you still only get the original 12 months without the new internship getting a fresh 12 months.*

For instance, starting a J1 short term scholar in another company before the first visa expire? *See previous answer*

Let's say I've got 6 months left with my current visa. Is it possible to cancel my current J1, go back in my country for three months and get a new J1 ? *Yes. You can repeat the J1 program multiple times. There is however a catch.
J-1 Intern to J-1 Intern = OK (as long as the internship plan shows that you’ll get different or higher level internship) [See](http://usainternship.com/can-i-repeat-my-j1-internship/#ixzz4Z4IbOJHO*)*

Is there other options than the J1 visa for a short term internship ? *NO*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From what I understand from your answer, cancelling a current J1 visa acts as if I had completed the program. Ex: if my visa expire in September, If I cancel it now and come back in Europe, I could start a new J1 Internship in June.

Comment: Do you have any idea why you have been downvoted ?

Comment: "Questions about immigration or moving for extended periods of time (studies or employment, among others) are off-topic